# Factory Reset without Factory Reset Protection

Tags: factory-reset

I've sold my old phone and perform Factory Reset to secure my data. After this the new user found that it's necessary to unlock phone with previous account.

Now, I've this user living nearby so I can perform a login of my account. But after that I want to reset my phone again to not allow him to recover my account/data.

If I perform again Factory Reset probably it will block again. How to perform a reset without enable this protection? (just for this phone and not all phone connected to this account)

Comment: remove google account before factory reset https://youtu.be/HTuoE33Kmp4